# Is there a math term for a modificated minimum spanning tree?

Tags: graph-theory, notation, terminology

I have found a minimum spanning tree (left figure). 
Then I have applied some modification:

1. The edge `A-B` (red) was added,
2. The edge `C-D` (green) was rewritten to `C'-D`.

**Edit.** I don't delete the vertices.

3. Steps 1-2 can be repeated more that one time for different edges.

> **Question.** Is there a math term for an obtained graph (right figure)?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well...it's no longer a tree, so I guess the best I can say is that it's a spanning subgraph. I'm not sure whether your "modifications" always preserve the property that the new graph contains all the vertices. If not, then you can just say "it's a subgraph."

Comment: I don't delete the vertices.

Comment: It is more than a subgraph : it is a $1$-tree.

Comment: In view of Nick's comment on your answer: I don't think it *is* a 1-tree. :) It's tough to know without a description of all possible "modifications."

Answer (score 0):

There is a term for this subgraph with a unique cycle: it is a [$1$-tree](http://kaminsky.ieor.berkeley.edu/ieor251/notes/3-16-05.pdf).

Some authors also call it a [pseudotree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoforest).

Comment: In my case I can add more than one cycle.